# JQuery DatePicker Binding

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to bind a datepicker to a list of dates returned via json and highlight them. Can anyone help or point to sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the [`beforeShowDay`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-beforeShowDay) event handler, for example:

**JavaScript:**

```
// Define an array of dates we want to highlight:

var dates = [ 
    new Date("02/13/2011"), 
    new Date("02/25/2011"), 
    new Date("03/01/2011") ];

// Set up the datepicker:


$("input").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        // Default result has no css class:
        var result = [true, '', null];
        // Determine if the date being rendered is in our array.
        // We cannot use $.inArray because dates are reference types:
        var matching = $.grep(dates, function(el) {
            return el.valueOf() === date.valueOf();
        });

        if (matching.length) {
            // Apply a class 'highlight' to dates that matched:
            result = [true, 'highlight', null];
        }
        return result;
    }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
table.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody td.highlight > a {
    background: url("images/ui-bg_inset-hard_55_ffeb80_1x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% bottom #FFEB80;
    color: #363636;
    border: 1px solid #FFDE2E;
}
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/VEjPK/

Hope that helps.